# ByteBuddy is it possible to use ASM to implement a method

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, byte-buddy

Is it possible to combine high level api of bytebuddy and low level api of asm?

I want to generate a class, its fields, annotations and some generic methods such as getters setters via bytebuddy since its much easier than asm.

But then i need to implement a single abstract class, where i need to use features that bytebuddy do not seems to support such as conditionals, branching, invoking another methods with unknown amount of arguments at compile time etc.

I stumbled upon `net.bytebuddy.implementation.bytecode.ByteCodeAppender` a class that exposes MethodVisitor, but I'm unable to find any examples how to use it correctly.

```
new ByteBuddy()
                .subclass(Base.class)
                .name(className)
                 ... define fields ...
                .defineMethod("testFor", Result.class, Ownership.MEMBER, Visibility.PUBLIC) //testFor is an abstract method on superclass that i inherit from  - public abstract Result testFor(Context c, WEnvironment env)
                .withParameters(Context.class, WEnvironment.class)
                .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(new ByteCodeAppenderImpl(...some ctr args...)));

class ByteCodeAppenderImpl implements ByteCodeAppender {

    <...ctr...>

 @Override
 public Size apply(MethodVisitor mv, Implementation.Context implContext, MethodDescription insnMethod) {

            mv.visitCode();
            mv.visitVarInsn(...);
            mv.visitFieldInsn(..)
            //Here i do required asm calls to implement the method
            .... 
            StackManipulation.Size operandStackSize = new StackManipulation.Compound().apply(methodVisitor, implementationContext);
            return new Size(operandStackSize.getMaximalSize(), instrumentedMethod.getStackSize());

}
```

By doing this im getting an exception:

```
None of [protected void java.lang.Object.finalize() throws java.lang.Throwable, public final void java.lang.Object.wait() throws java.lang.InterruptedException, public final void java.lang.Object.wait(long,int) throws java.lang.InterruptedException, public final native void java.lang.Object.wait(long) throws java.lang.InterruptedException, public boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object), public java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString(), public native int java.lang.Object.hashCode(), public final native java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass(), protected native java.lang.Object java.lang.Object.clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException, public final native void java.lang.Object.notify(), public final native void java.lang.Object.notifyAll(), public net.bytebuddy.implementation.bytecode.ByteCodeAppender$Size my.playground.BytebuddyPlayground08$ByteCodeAppenderImpl .apply(net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.MethodVisitor,net.bytebuddy.implementation.Implementation$Context,net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodDescription)] allows for delegation from public my.playground.Result my.playground.Custom1592066531191.testFor(my.playground.Context,my.playground.WEnvironment)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: None of [protected void java.lang.Object.finalize() throws java.lang.Throwable, public final void java.lang.Object.wait() throws java.lang.InterruptedException, public final void java.lang.Object.wait(long,int) throws java.lang.InterruptedException, public final native void java.lang.Object.wait(long) throws java.lang.InterruptedException, public boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object), public java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString(), public native int java.lang.Object.hashCode(), public final native java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass(), protected native java.lang.Object java.lang.Object.clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException, public final native void java.lang.Object.notify(), public final native void java.lang.Object.notifyAll(), public net.bytebuddy.implementation.bytecode.ByteCodeAppender$Size my.playground.BytebuddyPlayground08$ByteCodeAppenderImpl .apply(net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.MethodVisitor,net.bytebuddy.implementation.Implementation$Context,net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodDescription)] allows for delegation from public my.playground.Result my.playground.Custom1592066531191.testFor(my.playground.Context,my.playground.WEnvironment)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.MethodDelegationBinder$Processor.bind(MethodDelegationBinder.java:1096)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation$Appender.apply(MethodDelegation.java:1282)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyCode(TypeWriter.java:713)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyBody(TypeWriter.java:698)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod.apply(TypeWriter.java:605)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForCreation.create(TypeWriter.java:5133)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default.make(TypeWriter.java:1933)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:225)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:198)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase.make(DynamicType.java:3404)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase$Delegator.make(DynamicType.java:3600)
```

The Base.class I`m inheriting from, and its method i want to implement

```
public abstract class Base<T extends WEnvironment> extends ContextTest {

    public abstract Result testFor(Context c, T t);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct but you need to use a `Implementation` to provide your `ByteCodeAppender`. Using a `MethodDelegation` attempts a delegation to the object provided what does not make any sense as their is no meaningful delegation target what is what the exception is trying to tell you. You can simply wrap the appender using `new Implementation.Simple(...)` if you do not make any specific adjustments.

Comment: Can i make underlaying class/method writer to automatically calculate stack frame size? With pure asm this would mean to pass into ClassWriter constructor value of ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES

Comment: You can register a `ClassVisitorWrapper` and pass flags to ASM there.